# Is there anything similar to Haskell’s `$` in Unison?

Tags: unison-lang

In Haskell, `f $ g a` = `f (g a)`. Is there a right-associated operator like that in Unison?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options.

1. You can use `let`. For example, `f let g a` is the same as `f (g a)`. This is because `let` opens a [block](https://www.unison-lang.org/learn/language-reference/blocks-and-statements/), which is a sequence of statements. In this case the only statement in the block is the expression `g a` which becomes the value the block returns. So  you could write e.g.

   `isSome let head let List.map increment [1,2,3]`
2. There is a function application operator:

   `(base.Function.<|) : (a ->{e} b) -> a ->{e} b`

   so you could write `f <| g a`. However, Unison does not have any operator precedence rules, so *all operators associate to the left*. So if you want to do nested applications like

   `isSome <| (head <| List.map increment [1,2,3])`

   you will need to use parentheses anyway. However, since all operators associate to the left, you can just use the `|>` operator instead:

   `(base.Function.|>) : a -> (a ->{e} b) ->{e} b`

   Then you can write (flipping the order of the functions):

   `[1,2,3] |> List.map increment |> head |> isSome`
3. You can use function composition:

   `(base.Function.<<) : (b ->{e} c) -> (a ->{e} b) -> a ->{e} c`

   This lets you write

   `isSome << head << List.map increment <| [1,2,3]`

   Which is equivalent to the Haskell expression:

   `isJust . listToMaybe . map (+1) $ [1,2,3]`